# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a}{ {x^n} - a}$ converges for positive $x$, $\operatorname{sup}\{x^n\} > 1$, and $x^{n+1} \leq x^{n} \forall n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The sum of infinite series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a}{ {x^n} - a} $$
converges when $|x| > 1$ and $x^n \neq a$?

EDIT:

Does
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a}{ {x^n} - a} < +\infty\tag{1},$$
that is converge to some number between $[0, \infty)$ when the following holds?

- $a\geq0$ and $x^n \neq a \ \forall n$
- $\{x^n\}$ is positive
- Let $x^n$ be monotonically decreasing over increasing $n$, that is $1< x^{n+1} \leq x^n $. However, $\operatorname{sup} \{x^n \} > 1$.

NOTE: $\{ x^n\}$ is not a power series. One could replace $x^n$ with $x_n$ for clarity.

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133211/discussion-on-question-by-learning-prove-sum-n0-infty-fraca-xn-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$\operatorname{sup} \{x^n \} > 1
$
then
$x^n > 1$ for some $n$
so $x > 1$
so $x^n$
monotonically goes to $\infty$.

Therefore
there is an $n_0$ such that
$x^n > 2a$
for $n \gt n_0$
so
$x^n-a
\gt (x^n/2)+(x^n/2-a)
\gt x^n/2$
so,
for $n \gt n_0$,
$\frac{a}{ {x^n} - a}
\lt \frac{a}{x^n/2}
= \frac{2a}{x^n}
$
and the sum of this converges
since $x > 1$.