# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{ { \frac{x_n}{a^n}} - 1} < \infty$ for $0 \leq a < 1$ and $1 < x_{n+1} \leq x_{n} \forall n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In the other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356845/prove-sum-n-0-infty-fraca-xn-a-converges-for-positive-x-ope), I have fixed $a$. Here, I allow $a$ to be power series but not $x_n$.

Does
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{1}{ { \frac{x_n}{a^n}} - 1} < +\infty\tag{1},
\end{align}
that is converge to some number between $[0, \infty)$ when the following holds?

- $0 \leq a < 1$ and $x_n \neq a^n \ \forall n$
- $\{x_n\}$ is positive
- Let $x_n$ be monotonically decreasing over increasing $n$, that is $1< x_{n+1} \leq x_n $.
- Assume that $\frac{x_n}{a} > 1$.

NOTE: $\{x_n\}$ is not a power series.

Comment: You really need to put $x_n$ and not $x^n$, it adds needless confusion.

Comment: @Mike Thank you and I have edited now.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. These conditions are redundant though, if both $x_n \ge 1$ and $0<a<1$ then automatically $\frac{x_n}{a} > 1$.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n/x_n}{1-a^n/x_n} \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n/x_n}{1-a^n} \leq C\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a^n/x_n} \leq C \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \, , $$
for some constant $C$ which suffices to read of convergence.

Comment: $C=1/(1-a)$ would do, and the sum should start at $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a<1$ there is an integer $n_0(a)$ such that $a^{n} \le \frac{1}{2}$ for each $n \ge n_o(a)$. Thus:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right) \ \le \ \sum_{n=0}^{n_0(a)-1} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right) + \sum_{n=n_0(a)}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right)$$
Then using $a^n \le \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \ge n_0(a)$ and $x_n > 1$ for all $n$, gives $\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n} \le 2a^n$ for all $n \ge n_0(a)$, which in turn gives:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{n_0(a)-1} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right) + \sum_{n=n_0(a)}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right) $$
$$ \le \ \sum_{n=0}^{n_0(a)-1} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right) + \sum_{n=n_0(a)}^{\infty} 2a^n.$$

As each $x_n$ satisfies $x_n>1$, it follows that $\sum_{n=0}^{n_0(a)-1} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right)$ is a finite number of terms each finite, and so this is finite for each $a<1$. Also, as $\sum_{n=n_0(a)}^{\infty} 2a^n$ is a geometric series,
it follws that $\sum_{n=n_0(a)}^{\infty} 2a^n$ is bounded for $a<1$. Thus, it follows that  $\sum_{n=0}^{n_0(a)} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right) + \sum_{n=n_0(a)}^{\infty} 2a^n$ is bounded, and thus, so is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a^n}{x_n-a^n}\right)$.